# search customer in database with different number of search keys

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

found some other posts, but none of them really helped me (maybe I am too stupid for searching). Even the `Similar Questions` block while typing this did not help.

Here is my question:
I got a mysql database with 4 columns: id, first-name, last-name, city

On a php application I got an input field that queries via AJAX the php script to search the database. This field works if only 1 search term is given, like first-name. As soon I try 2 or 3 search terms I have no idea how to query the db.

Please help me how to query my database (got like 20,000 rows).
Some search examples:
`Thomas Boston`
`Michael Smith New York`
`Doe, Jane`
`Orlando, Michael`
Expected result are all rows that contain any of those search terms. Best would be to have it ordered by similarity (most terms found first). Using `DIFFERENCE()` would be nice, too, but my script is in German....

I have read stuff about full text search, but have no idea how to do this.

Here is my current query code (for 1 search term):

```
$key = $_GET['key'];
//Here will be something to filter all non numbers/letters and change them to a space for $key
$keys = explode(" ",$key); //$keys is not in use yet
$prep_stmt = "
SELECT 
    id, last-name, first-name, city 
FROM 
    customers 
WHERE 
    last-name LIKE concat('%', ? ,'%') OR
    first-name LIKE concat('%', ? ,'%')  OR
    city LIKE concat('%', ? ,'%') 
ORDER BY 
    last-name ASC";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $key, $key, $key);
```

About security: This code runs in an internal environment. So security is not the biggest priority.

PS: I am not native English, but I tried my best.

---

Stuff I found, but didn't help:

- [Performing a search on first and last name columns with a single search string that has more than 2 words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182365/performing-a-search-on-first-and-last-name-columns-with-a-single-search-string-t)
- [Searching full name or first or last name in MySQL database with first and last name in separate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046741/searching-full-name-or-first-or-last-name-in-mysql-database-with-first-and-last)
- [Search with full name instead of just first name or last name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349619/search-with-full-name-instead-of-just-first-name-or-last-name)
- [Live search on first, middle and last name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988743/live-search-on-first-middle-and-last-name)
- [Search Database by First and Last Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058868/search-database-by-first-and-last-name)
- [MySQL Search For Names - Separated by Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208548/mysql-search-for-names-separated-by-space)

---

~~EDIT~~

Stuff I came up with, but didn't work:

```
$key = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/u", ' ', $key)));

SELECT
    id, last-name, first-name, city 
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    last-name LIKE concat('%', REPLACE( ? ,' ','%') ,'%') OR
    first-name LIKE concat('%', REPLACE( ? ,' ','%') ,'%') OR
    city LIKE concat('%', REPLACE( ? ,' ','%') ,'%')                
ORDER BY
    name ASC
```

Comment: It would make your like so much easier if you passed some sensible well organised parameters from your AJAX i.e. put things in variables like `{fname: "Thomas", city: "Boston}` rather than just spraying data at your PHP script in an unorganised unmanagable fashion. Currnetly how would you distinguish betweena  firstname a lastname or a city?

Comment: This would so nice and so much easier, but I cannot control the user. There is only 1 input field and user has to be able to search for first name, last name and city in any way you could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rogier Bruggeman I got an idea how to solve my problem. This is how I solved it:

```
$key = $_GET['key'];
$key = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/u", ' ', $key)));
$keys = explode(" ",$key);
$key_num = count($keys);
if(NOT RELEVANT == RELEVANT){
    NOT RELEVANT
} else {
    //prepare statement
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id  FROM customers WHERE ";
    if($key_num == 1){
        $prep_stmt .= "
            lastname LIKE ? OR
            firstame LIKE ? OR
            zip LIKE ? OR
            city LIKE ?
        ORDER BY
            lastname ASC";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
        $key = '%' . $key . '%';
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $key, $key, $key, $key);
    } else {
        $p = 0;
        foreach($keys as $v){
            if($p <> 0){
                $prep_stmt .= " AND ";
            }
            $prep_stmt .= "(lastname LIKE ? OR firstname LIKE ? OR zip LIKE ? OR city LIKE ? )";
            $p++;
        }
        $prep_stmt .= " ORDER BY name ASC";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
        switch($key_num){
            case 2:
                $keys[0] = '%' . $keys[0] . '%';
                $keys[1] = '%' . $keys[1] . '%';
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[1]);
                break;
            case 3:
                $keys[0] = '%' . $keys[0] . '%';
                $keys[1] = '%' . $keys[1] . '%';
                $keys[2] = '%' . $keys[2] . '%';
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssss', $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[2], $keys[2], $keys[2], $keys[2]);
                break;
            case 4:
                $keys[0] = '%' . $keys[0] . '%';
                $keys[1] = '%' . $keys[1] . '%';
                $keys[2] = '%' . $keys[2] . '%';
                $keys[3] = '%' . $keys[3] . '%';
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssss', $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[2], $keys[2], $keys[2], $keys[2], $keys[3], $keys[3], $keys[3], $keys[3]);
                break;
            case 5:
                $keys[0] = '%' . $keys[0] . '%';
                $keys[1] = '%' . $keys[1] . '%';
                $keys[2] = '%' . $keys[2] . '%';
                $keys[3] = '%' . $keys[3] . '%';
                $keys[4] = '%' . $keys[4] . '%';
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssssss', $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[2], $keys[2], $keys[2], $keys[2], $keys[3], $keys[3], $keys[3], $keys[3], $keys[4], $keys[4], $keys[4], $keys[4]);
                break;
            case 6:
                $keys[0] = '%' . $keys[0] . '%';
                $keys[1] = '%' . $keys[1] . '%';
                $keys[2] = '%' . $keys[2] . '%';
                $keys[3] = '%' . $keys[3] . '%';
                $keys[4] = '%' . $keys[4] . '%';
                $keys[5] = '%' . $keys[5] . '%';
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssssssssss', $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[0], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[1], $keys[2], $keys[2], $keys[2], $keys[2], $keys[3], $keys[3], $keys[3], $keys[3], $keys[4], $keys[4], $keys[4], $keys[4], $keys[5], $keys[5], $keys[5], $keys[5]);
                break;
            default:
                $stmt = "SELECT id FROM customer WHERE 1 LIKE 2";
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
        }

    }
```

It is kind of dirty, but it works. Really dirty is my `default` in the `switch`

Answer (score -1):

You need to loop the $keys to extend your query

```
$prep_stmt = "
    SELECT 
        id, last-name, first-name, city 
    FROM 
        customers 
    WHERE ";

foreach($key as $v)
{
    $prep_stmt .= " OR last-name LIKE concat('%'%') OR
    first-name LIKE concat('%', ? ,'%')  OR
    city LIKE concat('%', ? ,'%') OR  " ;
}
$prep_stmt .= " 1 
ORDER BY 
    last-name ASC
";
```

Then bind each param separately, once for each ?

$p = 1;
foreach($key as $v)
{
    $stmt->bindParam($p++,$v);
    $stmt->bindParam($p++,$v);
    $stmt->bindParam($p++,$v);
}

Comment: Did you mean to suddenly switch from `mysqli` syntax to `PDO` syntax?

Comment: Thanks. This actually brought me on the right track.

Comment: @user2129866 You accepted this but it is not a correct answer. That is not going to help other that have a similiar issue and see this as an accepted  answer

Comment: true @RiggsFolly He gave me the idea to solve my issue, but I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer :(